# How can I index a QTableWidget by field name?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm bug fixing someone else's Qt code, and this involves adding some extra columns to a QTableWidget. The current code indexes columns by their integer index. I would like to change this code so that it indexes by the header name. The code at the moment looks a bit like this:

```
// column 1 => Semantics
// column 2 => algorithm
// colunm 3 => ...
// ...

tableWidget->setItemDelegateForColumn(0, semanticsDelegate);
tableWidget->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, algorithmsDelegate);
tableWidget->setItemDelegateForColumn(2, specDelegate);
```

I would like to change it to something like this:

```
tableWidget->setItemDelegateForColumn(foo("Semantics"), semanticsDelegate);
tableWidget->setItemDelegateForColumn(foo("Algorithm"), algorithmsDelegate);
tableWidget->setItemDelegateForColumn(foo("..."), specDelegate);
```

Is this possible in Qt? (The QTableWidget columns are titled "Semantics", "Algorithm", etc) Or will I have to make an enum of table fields to handle this?

Comment: I would use enum to name the column numbers: `enum { Semantics, Algorithm, Foo };` because I don't see any reason in converting integers to strings and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item delegates are indexed by an `int`so, if you want to proceede in that way, you must to provide a function to map the column header to an unique integer. How to implement that `foo()` function is up to you - an enum and a `QList< QPair<QString,enum_item> >` should be good for you - . If your app will be translated, don't forget to use [Qt's i18n facilities](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-i18n.html)